# When is service connection completed for water / sewer for new construction?

Tags: water, sewer, inspection, utilities

Is it after Final Inspection that the lines are run from the house to the street? I'd like to hire a contractor for the service connection portion and need to know at what point in the process this is done. I'm in the US.

Comment: Have you called a contractor to ask this question?  They would be able to answer very specifically based on your location.

Comment: @DanGNelson I think this also depends on your locality with in the USA.
I think the lines can be run from the house to the street but not turned on until after final inspection - if I am not mistaken they are locked at the supply side. Your local water company should know the exact answer to your question. I recall something on this but not enough to specifically say it is this way. As I said states and municipalities have different standards and yours is relevant to your state and municipality. I think in Fl it is locked until inspection.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, tie-ins are done in conjunction with the locality (town/city maintenance) and are done independently of the state inspections. This is because of locality-specific backflow prevention devices.

You see, hypothetically, nowhere in code do I need a backflow prevention device for sewer in my house in town. However, because I have a full basement, and my plumbing runs lower than the town's sewer system, it'd be in the best interest of all concerned for me to install one.

Get with your local contractor. He/she knows what to do.